# Why do I get segmentation fault when I compile and run this code?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, printf, dereference

I am trying to create a char pointer array,or another way to put it a string array; using this syntax:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char **a = {"ab", "ac"};
    printf("%c", *((*a)+sizeof(char)));
}
```

To my understanding, `a` is a pointer that points to a `char*`. When I dereference it, I must access to the `char*` which in this context is the pointer that points to the first `char` of the string literal `"ab"`. Adding one byte to the pointer must yield the pointer, address that points to the second `char` to the string literal, and when dereferenced, it must yield the `char`: `'b'`? So why does this chunk of code generate such error? Is it because the compiler doesn't allocate adequate amount of memory because I am m erely declaring a pointer instead of an array? The prior questions are just speculations and are optional for one to answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first stop should be compiler warnings.

Comment: `char **a = {"ab", "ac"};` doesn't do what you apparently think it does. And the compiler should have [warned you about it](https://godbolt.org/z/h3W6n5roh).

Comment: On another note, for any pointer or array `a` and index `i`, the expression `*(a + i)` is *exactly* equal to `a[i]`. The latter syntax (using "array" indexing) is much more clearer and simpler to read and understand. From this equivalence it's also possible to deduce that `*a*` is equal to `a[0]`. Also remember that `sizeof(char)` is specified to *always* be `1`.

Comment: and when used in pointer arithmetic `1` means "1 unit of the object's size".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the suggestions, what does `char **a = {"ab", "ac"};` do exactly?

Comment: @explorer It is simply wrong.

Comment: It's the same as `char **a = "ac";` Which is clearly wrong. Use an array: `const char *a[] = { "ab", "ac" };`

Comment: @explorer Also, don't ignore your compiler's warnings.

Comment: @Zakk they are not comprehensible for one that is new to the language, therefore I dismiss them

Comment: Compiler warnings should really be treated as *errors*, and that you must fix. Never dismiss messages from the compiler. Especially for a beginner, the compiler will know more about the code than you do.

Comment: Also, as a beginner you should learn that code like the one you posted here should not be considered a good example of anything. It's a *bad* example, besides the errors it's very hard to decipher for a beginner. Whomever taught you to write code like that should not be considered a good teacher.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude why is it such a bad example apart from the invalid "array declaration"?

Comment: Using pointer arithmetic instead of array indexing is unclear and hard to read and understand, especially for beginners. Same with using `sizeof(char)` here, which isn't really relevant in this case (and can give wrong ideas when using pointer arithmetic for other (non-character) arrays). What you seem to want is `a[0][1]`, which is easy to read and understand (and much less to write!).

Answer (score 2):

This declaration

```
char **a = {"ab", "ac"};
```

is incorrect. You may not initialize a scalar object with a braced list that contains more than one initializing expression.

Instead you could declare an array like

```
char * a[] = {"ab", "ac"};
```

And if you want to output the second character of the first string literal used as an initializer then you can write for example

```
printf( "%c", *( *a + 1 ) );
```

Or you could declare an intermediate pointer like

```
char * a[] = {"ab", "ac"};
char **p = a;
```

and then

```
printf( "%c", *( *p + 1 ) );
```

If you want to output the whole array using pointers then the corresponding program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char * a[] = {"ab", "ac"};

    for ( char **p = a; p != a + sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ); ++p )
    {
        for ( char *q = *p; *q; ++q )
        {
            printf( "%c", *q );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
ab
ac
```

Answer (score 2):

`char**` is not an array and cannot be used as one. Except for the scenario when it points at the first item in an array of `char*`.

`char **a = {"ab", "ac"};` is not valid C, as the compiler told you with warnings. You might want to consider a different configuration so that you won't have to waste time on things like this, see [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

You *could* however turn this incorrect line into a valid one by having the `char**` point at the first item of an array. This can be done with the aid of a *compound literal*:

```
char **a = (char*[]){"ab", "ac"};
```

Please note however that the string literals in this code are read-only, so correct code should actually be:

```
const char **a = (const char*[]){"ab", "ac"};
```

Though maybe just drop the pointer to pointer entirely since it fills no obvious purpose here and go with a plain array instead:

```
const char* a[] = {"ab", "ac"};
```

Comment: Can you link the self-answered Q&A that you wrote about the difference between pointers and arrays? It is very useful.

Comment: @Zakk In case you mean [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays), then I'd rather not, since arrays of pointers to strings is one of the valid uses of pointer-to-pointers. Also there's no dynamic allocation in this case.